# Set a custom icon for HTML color input

Tags: html, css, button

I want the user to be able to open the color dialog box to set 'ForeColor' and 'BackgroundColor'. So I use this:

```
<span class="insertPicLabel">ForeColor</span>
<input type="color" id="fontColorButton" title="Change Font Color">
<span class="insertPicLabel">Highlight</span>
<input type="color" id="highlightButton" title="Highlight text Color">
```

Which works fine but doesn't look nice. I wish to use a button with an icon instead. I tried to set an background image but the color bar always shows over it.

What can I do? Is there another method I could use to open the color dialog box like a regular button as with VB?

Comment: Could you add an image / a snippet? An image with the desired result would also help.

Comment: @rpm192. I tried to add an image in the background but it doesn't show. So I removed it after. The code above is what left...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
<span class="insertPicLabel">ForeColor</span>
<input type="color" id="fontColorButton" title="Change Font Color">

<button class="xx btn-default"><i class="fas fa-palette"></i>open  box </button>

<script>
$(".xx").on('click', function(){
  $("#fontColorButton").click();
})
</script>
```

libraries used : Jquery , bootsrtap , fontawesome

please refer to this link for reference : 
https://codepen.io/singhagam1/pen/MZVrrJ

or if you want to hide the input type , just hide it initially or give it style="display :none "

Comment: If there a way I could do it in plain old Javascript? I would prefer to get to learn that a little better before using Jquery or other... I think I  see what you mean by giving a style="display:none". I tried a couple things without success.... Could you give me an example?

Comment: @DidierTibule
Please check the above code pen as i have updated it with javascript i.e. without jquery 
feel free to question if i still din't resolve your query

Comment: Can I ask again your help? The solution you proposed works as wanted. But I have a problem with it that I cannot understand. I use that button for the user to select colors in a basic rich text box. The writings are in a iframe. But when the function is called the iframe clears of all content just before the color dialog box pops... Any idea why?

Comment: Yes for sure i can help you with that , 
if you can create a code pen for the same or show me the code , because its a little difficult to claim anything without it

Comment: Thanks. But finally I went for a different solution. The color dialog box was a bit of an overkill anyway for what I wanted to do. So I went for a drop down box with a few basic colors to chose from. I don't get to have the icon though... But be certain I will pick your brains again sooner then later!  :-)

Comment: For sure , anytime :)

Comment: Well then... :) I'm still battling with the input types. And now I have that little problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072736/problem-passing-value-of-an-input-into-an-iframe